# Convert Excel date to xsd datetime in c#

Tags: c#, xml, excel, datetime, xsd

I've got a date from an Excel worksheet when I serialize an xml. One of the entries is a datetime in a special format. Only this format is accepted:
2015-02-02T08:00:00+02

The input from Excel is: 2015. 02. 02 13:40

The actual output is: 2015-02-02T13:40:00+01:00

The required output is: 2015-02-02T13:40:00+01

How can I achieve this? I've tried a lot of things, but I couldn't come up with a working solution.

Currently I have this, but it doesn't give the required result:

```
freight.loadDateSpecified = DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToString(workSheet.Range["T" + row.ToString()].Value), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out expiration);
freight.loadDate = XmlConvert.ToDateTime(expiration.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszz"),"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");
```

Thanks

Comment: "it doesn't give the required result" doesn't tell us what the input is, what the expected output is, or what the actual output is.

Comment: I updated my question to be more accurate

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference between the required and actual output.

Comment: Ah, that's more like it.

Comment: +01:00 vs +01

the webservice i have to use only accepts +01.

Comment: Try using `zz` instead of `zzz` in your call...

Comment: (It's not entirely clear to me why you're using XmlConvert at all, to be honest... or which of those two values is the one causing problems... or where you're getting that string from, when both of the fields/properties appear to be DateTime, not string...)

Comment: zz instead of zzz not working. If I simply use the date then it will be in the following format: 2015-02-02T13:40. I'm stucked, I don't know how to produce this date form.

Comment: I've tried this one too: 

Convert.ToDateTime(expiration.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszz"));

It gives the same result: +01:00 instead of +01.

Comment: But all of these are just creating DateTime values - that doesn't have a particular string format.

Comment: But the webservice only accepts in +01 format. I'm sure there must be a way to achieve this, but can't figure out.

If I change the field and property from DateTime to string, then I can format the string as I want, but the webservice doesn't accept that neither.

Comment: I think you've missed the point - the problem isn't in your code, it's in how .NET is converting your objects into strings for the web service call. It doesn't help that you haven't told us *anything* about that (indeed, your question doesn't even mention a web service). Fundamentally it sounds like the web service is broken, and you should *at least* complain to its authors, as +01:00 is entirely valid for [xsd:dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#dateTime) but beyond that, you should also turn your focus to how you're talking to the web service - as we have no info about that now.